# Sobel edge detector using C++ without any special library or tool

Tags: c++, image

I am trying to implement the SObel edge detector in C++ WITHOUT using any special library for image processing. I am not sure why the following code just doesn't do the job (the output image shows a messy grayish picture. THe image format is PPM. I'd be grateful for any advise/comment/help. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

//a class that represents the three colour values (R,G,B) in each pixel. 

class Pixel {   private:

  unsigned int P1, P2, P3;


  public:

  Pixel () {};   
 void setPixels (unsigned int Pixel1, unsigned int Pixel2, unsigned int Pixel3);        
unsigned int getPixel1 ();   unsigned int getPixel2 ();   unsigned int getPixel3 (); };


  void Pixel::setPixels (unsigned int Pixel1, unsigned int Pixel2, unsigned int Pixel3)   {
      P1 = Pixel1;
      P2 = Pixel2;
      P3 = Pixel3;   }

  unsigned int Pixel::getPixel1 ()   {
      return P1;   }

  unsigned int Pixel::getPixel2 ()   {
      return P2;   }

  unsigned int Pixel::getPixel3 ()   {
      return P3;   }


//*****************int main () stars here! *****************

int main () {
    //information contained in the header file is represented by the following variables

    unsigned char Magic [2];
    unsigned int TotRows = 512;
    unsigned int TotCol = 512;
    unsigned int MaxVal = 255;



    int size = (3 * TotRows * TotCol);

    char *charImage = new char [size];

    //opening original image
    ifstream OldImage;
    OldImage.open ("image.ppm", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (!OldImage)
    {
       cout << "\nError: Cannot open image file! " << endl;
    }

     //reading the header of the original image file
     OldImage >> Magic [0] >> Magic [1] >>  TotRows >>  TotCol >> MaxVal;

       OldImage.read(charImage, size);

         unsigned int val1, val2, val3;

         //an array of pixels, which is used to represent the image
         Pixel **PixelVal;

         PixelVal = new Pixel* [TotRows];
         int T=0;

//Reading the image data and setting the pixels values as unsigned integers
    for(int i=0; i < TotRows; i++)
    {
        PixelVal[i] = new Pixel [TotCol];

        for(int j=0; j < TotCol; j++)
        {
            val1 = (unsigned int)charImage[T];
            val2 = (unsigned int)charImage[T+1];
            val3 = (unsigned int)charImage[T+2];
            PixelVal[i][j].setPixels (val1, val2, val3);
            T=T+3;
        }
    }


   if (OldImage.fail())
    {
        cout << "Can't read image " << endl;
    }

OldImage.close();


//Calculating the grayscale in each pixel. 
//The values of the 3 colours (R, B and G) are all the same  
for(int i=0; i < TotRows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < TotCol; j++)
        {
val1=(PixelVal[i][j].getPixel1()+PixelVal[i][j].getPixel1()+PixelVal[i][j].getPixel1())/3;
            val2=val1;
            val3=val1;
            PixelVal[i][j].setPixels(val1, val2, val3);
        }
    }


unsigned int valX, valY = 0; unsigned int GX [3][3]; unsigned int GY [3][3];

//Sobel Horizontal Mask     
GX[0][0] = 1; GX[0][1] = 0; GX[0][2] = -1; 
GX[1][0] = 2; GX[1][1] = 0; GX[1][2] = -2;  
GX[2][0] = 1; GX[2][1] = 0; GX[2][2] = -1;

//Sobel Vertical Mask   
GY[0][0] =  1; GY[0][1] = 2; GY[0][2] =   1;    
GY[1][0] =  0; GY[1][1] = 0; GY[1][2] =   0;    
GY[2][0] = -1; GY[2][1] =-2; GY[2][2] =  -1;


//SOBEL edge detector implementation. 
//Note: in each Pixel, the values of the 3 colours is the same.Therefore 
//the calculation is performed on the first one only. The other 2 colours are
// then set to be = to the first one.

 for(int i=0; i < TotRows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < TotCol; j++)
        {

            //setting the pixels around the border to 0, 
           //because the Sobel kernel cannot be allied to them
            if ((i==0)||(i==TotRows-1)||(j==0)||(j==TotCol-1))
            {
               valX=0;
               valY=0;
            }

            else
            {
                //calculating the X and Y convolutions
                for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
                    {
                        valX = valX + PixelVal[i+x][j+y].getPixel1() * GX[1+x][1+y];
                        valY = valY + PixelVal[i+x][j+y].getPixel1() * GY[1+x][1+y];
                    }
                }
            }

            //Gradient magnitude
             val1 = sqrt(valX*valX + valY*valY);

            //setting the new pixel value
            PixelVal[i][j].setPixels(val1, val1, val1);
        }
    }

//creating a new file to host the copied image
    ofstream NewImage;
    NewImage.open ("image1.ppm", ios::out | ios::binary);

    if (!NewImage)
    {
        cout << "\nError: Cannot open image file! " <<endl;
    }

//writing the header in the new image file
    NewImage << "P6" << endl << TotRows << " " << TotCol << " " << MaxVal << endl;


T=0;
     for(int i=0; i < TotRows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < TotCol; j++)
        {
        val1 = PixelVal[i][j].getPixel1();
        val2 = PixelVal[i][j].getPixel2();
        val3 = PixelVal[i][j].getPixel3();
        charImage[T]=(unsigned char)val1;
        charImage[T+1]=(unsigned char)val2;
        charImage[T+2]=(unsigned char)val3;
        T=T+3;
        }
    }

cout << T;

    NewImage.write(charImage, size);

    if (NewImage.fail())
    {
        cout << "Can't write image " << endl;
    }

NewImage.close(); delete [] charImage;

for (int i = 0; i < TotRows; i++)
     {
         delete [] PixelVal[i];
     }

     delete [] PixelVal;


    return 0; }
```

Comment: You don't zero `valX` and `valY` before summing each pixel

Comment: Your code has some deeper issues though. For example, you're copying the entire image into another structure (which you malloc and free every time) before processing it, which is slow, and converting all pixels to `int` unnecessarily (they can be converted inside the inner loop during the calculation). Also you're using arrays of arrays when you could use a single array (`index = y*width+x`).

Comment: THanks! I edited the code after your first reply because I noticed there was some formatting issue. I think I initialized valX and valY to 0 (right before the masks). Is it correct? THanks so much for checking it out.

Comment: nope, that's not correct. Look at the loops you have and imagine what the values will be set to at each point. Or spoilers: on the first iteration, `valX` is uninitalised (so could be anything), on the second, `valX` and `valY` still hold the results from the first loop, etc, etc. As the loop progresses, you get bigger and bigger numbers, which (because it must fit within an int) produces pseudo-random noise.

Comment: Dave you are my hero!!! I've been staring at the darn code for so long... It works amazing now and I will definitely take onboard all your suggestions about making the code more efficient. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dave if you add your post to the answer section I will upvote it, so this post shows as having and answer and you get the cred.

Comment: Well, I posted it as an answer, although this is a more specific problem than Stack Overflow is meant for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valX` and `valY` are not being zeroed inside your loop, so they are getting bigger and bigger. By fitting them inside an int, you get pseudo-random noise.

All you need to do is add `valX = valY = 0;` where you have "calculating the X and Y convolutions".